# mySQL Workbench Importing

Tags: mysql-workbench

I was trying to import it but i am encountering some errors.

this is my error:

> 08:49:13 PM Restoring dbDB (contact)
>   Running: mysql --defaults-extra-file="/tmp/tmpdwf14l/extraparams.cnf"  --host=127.0.0.1 --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments 
>   ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 22: No database selected
>
> Operation failed with exitcode 1
>   08:49:13 PM Restoring dbDBB (course)
>   Running: mysql --defaults-extra-file="/tmp/tmpMW20Fb/extraparams.cnf"  --host=127.0.0.1 --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 
>   ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 22: No database selected

Comment: Google "mysql no database selected" of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Error:` You have not selected the default target schema in which to import the data from dump 
Create a schema/database in MySQL and select that database in MySQL Workbench while importing data from Dump.

`Or`
You can edit the dump file and append a SQL statement at the start with some thing like this

```
create database test;
use test;
```

[image: Select the default target schema]

`Solution as per the dump file of user:`

```
--
-- Table structure for table `course`
--
```

Write the code as :

```
create database test1;
use test1;
--
-- Table structure for table `course`
--
```

This should do.

Comment: @Pink000 Open up the dump file and append those lines at first.
Or if you are using MySQL Workbencg you can create a database and then select it in the default target schema (as shown above in the picture). that would be easier for you.

Comment: THanks! i did it, but i have a question. Why is it happening only to me, when my classmates just do the same and not encounter any error? Have I missed something?

Comment: @Pink000 See the updated answer, Your friend might have created a new database to import the dump file or would have used a existing database to import the dump file. No Biggie.  [Do mark the solution as answer if it has served your purpose for others to benefit]

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you havent selected any database; In the dump right below `create schema 'database_name'` (or create database 'database_name') add this : `use 'database_name';`

Replace the database_name with your DB name;